# selecting the color of preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

Setting the theme, but whenever the color has been set the text color doesn't change on the dynamically made preferences.

```
<style name="PreferenceScreen" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:color">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

This is how the preferences are added:

```
Vector<String> categories = getCategories();

//Add all the categories to the preference
PreferenceCategory cat = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_key");

for (final String categoryTitle : categories){
    final Preference pref = new Preference(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    pref.setTitle(categoryTitle);
    pref.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.list_black_text);
    cat.addPreference(pref);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.list_item)` instead of `pref.setWidgetLayoutResource()`.

You can define colors and styles in the above mentioned  `layout/list_item.xml`, which should be something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:maxLines="10" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

- `@+android:id/title` will be filled with your title;
- `@+android:id/summary` with your summary;
- `@+android:id/widget_frame` with anything you set up using `pref.setWidgetLayoutResource()` (may it be a `CheckBox`, or a `Switch`, or whatever).

Just add XML attributes to change text color where needed.

Comment: After I set the layout I need to be able to change the titles. I would have trouble accessing the IDs from the preferences since there isn't a way I found to be able to get the views from the fragment.

Comment: You don't need to fill the views yourself. If you call pref.setTitle() and then apply your custom layout, title will be automatically loaded into related textView. You can't work with Ids, that's why we are using those already recognized by Preference classes.